# How can I do the following in latex

Tags: formatting

I am new to latex. I have recently started to work with it. I have basic understanding.
But still I am trying hard to get the things done. I am struck here.

I want some thing like this below on my title page:

```
Name:                    Advisor:
Mr. X                    Advisor's name
logo-image.png           Co-Advisor:
                         Co-Advisor's name
```

I tried to play with `\begin{flushleft}` `\begin{flushright}` but what I get is following:

```
Name:                    
Mr. X                    
logo-image.jpeg              
                             Advisor:
                             Advisor's name
                             Co-Advisor:
                             Co-Advisor's name
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A [`tabular`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) would do.

Comment: Use [`minipage`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox) environment.

Comment: a `list` environment might work, such as `itemize`

Comment: Currently I am trying with tabular. I'll let you all know if it worked out.

Comment: @Manuel I tried tabular. But there is problem due to the image. Please find my new question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193338/23349

Comment: @pss: Is it really necessary to open a new question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If I edit this question, then maybe some users will ask me Why I edited this one? Basically I was confused. I was unable to express my problem in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please always post full test documents but basically

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
Name\\
Mr X\\
\includegraphics{file}
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
Advisor\\
zz\\
xx
\end{tabular}
```

will put the two text blocks either side of the page, aligned on their top lines