# Problem due to an image inserted in a table

Tags: formatting

This is my follow up question. My previous question is here: [How can I do the following in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193328/23349)

**Problem**:

If I add the image in my table, I get the following output as shown in the image below. Why is the Co-Supervisor going below?

[image: Table problem]
I am using this code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
\bf Author: & \hspace{5pt} & \bf Research Supervisor:\\
\hline
Mr. X &  \hspace{5pt} & Prof. Dr. Z\\
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,height=10mm]{Figures/images} &  \hspace{5pt} & \bf Co-Supervisor:\\
\hline
&  \hspace{5pt} & Prof. Dr. Y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

What I want is shown below:
[image]

**PS:** Please ignore the table borders, they are for demo only, I won't be using them in my final code.

**The final product:** that I desire is:

[image]

Comment: Please post a MWE always, not just fragments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image can be aligned with "Prof. Dr. Y" by using a nested `tabular` with optional option `b` (bottom):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|!{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}|r|}
\hline
\bfseries Author: & \bfseries Research Supervisor:\\
\hline
Mr.\ X & Prof.\ Dr.\ Z\\
\hline
\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,height=10mm]{Figures/images} &
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
  \bfseries Co-Supervisor:\\
  Prof.\ Dr.\ Y
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l!{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}r}
\bfseries Author: & \bfseries Research Supervisor:\\
Mr.\ X & Prof.\ Dr.\ Z\\
\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,height=10mm]{Figures/images} &
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
  \bfseries Co-Supervisor:\\
  Prof.\ Dr.\ Y
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\bf` is the name in plain TeX and LaTeX 2.09. LaTeX 2<sub>ε</sub> uses `\bfseries`.
- `Prof. Dr. Z`: TeX does not know, that the dots do not end a sentence, with `\nonfrenchspacing`, the space is therefore larger. This can be avoided by `\Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Z` or `Prof.\ Dr.\ Z` or `Prof.~Dr.~Z`. BTW, if the letter before the dot is an uppercase letter, TeX sets the normal inter word space, because it assumes, the the dot is an abbreviation dot.
- `\hspace{5pt}` as cell contents has no effect. TeX surrounds the cell with `\ignorespaces` at the beginning and `\unskip` at the end. The latter removes the previous `\hspace`. The space that can be seen is `\tabcolsep` at both sides. Therefore the example has added the space via `!{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}` (needs package `array`) and has dropped the middle column.

## Two tables for the left and right side

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
  \bfseries Author:\\
  Mr.\ X\\
  \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,height=10mm]{Figures/images}\\
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{r}
  \bfseries Research Supervisor:\\
  Prof.\ Dr.\ Z\\
  \bfseries Co-Supervisor:\\
  Prof.\ Dr.\ Y\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, one question Why is the Co-Supervisor not sticking to the bottom of Prof. Dr. Z. I don't want that space. For eg: the image is sticking to MR. X perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `\multirow` approach:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%

\begin{document}

\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\textbf{Author}: & \hspace{5pt} & Research Supervisor:\tabularnewline
Mr. X & \hspace{5pt}  & Prof. Dr. Z\tabularnewline
\multirow{2}{*}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,height=10mm]{Figures/images}}%
 & \hspace{5pt} & Co-Supervisor:\\
& \hspace{5pt} & Prof. Dr. Y\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\normalfont


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am using `\documentclass{report}`. :(

Comment: @ρss — It doesn't matter.

Comment: @pss: How should Heiko or I know about `report`? There is no indication ;-)

Comment: @Manuel Yes you are right and I am left. I really need to work on my latex skills.

Comment: @pss: As Manuel wrote: No difference for the table itself

Comment: @ρss By the way, take a note on Christian comment: a full compilable example is always better than just a snippet.

Comment: Yes, I'll be careful next time. Thanks all.